# In Selenium/Python trying to find all Buttons with that meet certain criteria by xpath so it can be clicked

Tags: selenium, xpath

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW5rp.png)

I'm currently working with Selenium and Python to create a script that helps with booking free spots on a website for internships so you don't have to check it all the time.

So I'm trying to express an xpath which will lead selenium to find all free spots and click the "book" button.

My **first question** is if you could somehow shortcut the loop in the code below so it doesn't have to go through each value one by one but just finds all Buttons which have `x as a value >=1` in the text attribute. (The text attribute contains the number of currently available spots and overall spots.

**Second problem** would be how to address the buttons who have spots available so they can be clicked and, in the end, hopefully booked. First I tried it with selenium going through every cell of the html table  to check if the button can be clicked and the spot booked but that takes to too much time I figure

```
browser.get('https://www.pj-portal.de/index_hro.php?PAGE_ID=101')

delay = 2


for x in range(1,20):

 browser.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//*[contains(text(),'{x}/')]")
 print("found")
 Liste1 = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//*[contains(text(),'{x}/')]")
 print(len(Liste1))




 Wunschbutton = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(//td[text()='1/3']/preceding-sibling::td[2])
 Wunschbutton.click()
```

[Screenshot of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW5rp.png)

A part of the HTML Page:

```
<td class="aktion verfuegbar  buchungsphase  border_links"
<img class="aktion_tertial_wunsch_setzen " data- 
 pj_traineeship_tertial_id="166037" data- 
 pj_general_traineeship_id="8487" data-changetype="24" 
 src="images/wunsch_setzen_button.svg" alt="+" title="Wunsch"> 
</td><img class="aktion_tertial_wunsch_setzen " data- 
 pj_traineeship_tertial_id="166037" data- 
 pj_general_traineeship_id="8487" data-changetype="24" 
 src="images/wunsch_setzen_button.svg" alt="+" title="Wunsch">

<td class="hinweise_leer  verfuegbar  buchungsphase "> </td>

<td class=" tertial_verfuegbarkeit verfuegbar  buchungsphase  
">1/3</td>
```

Maybe someone has an idea. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how did you figure out the range

```
range(1,20):
```

in advance.

To answer your first question, I would say you can narrow down the search from xpath.

Something like this:

```
//*[starts-with(text(),'1/')]
```

Now using this XPath you will make sure that you are only looking for rows which has `1/*` in the third column.

to answer your second query I think you can have a check at `row color`, if it's red then all the seats are available or no seat is available. [Depends on how the application is designed]. Would need more context to answer this part.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The 20 is just a random number, to start off with. Some "provider" have up to free 24 spots, don't know if thats the upper limit though. These wouldn't have been found anyways by the range.
Yes! I was also wondering if I could just look for the colour but I didn't know how, couldn't find any clue if I look through the HTML code with the web developer section. 
Basically I just want selenium to find available spots and click them. If they are clicked a second button appears which confirms the booking. I also need to imply some priorities in case two spaces are free

Comment: Do you have test creds that I can use to login and see the HTML code by myself?

Comment: Also, was `//*[starts-with(text(),'1/')]` helpful to filter out the things ?

Comment: I only have my own login data.. Can I get you insight a different way?
//*[starts-with(text(),'1/')] that one worked perfectly! Found exaclty both cells where places were available, thank you very much for that!

Comment: Without seeing the HTML, it will be difficult to answer the second part. Why don't you create a new thread for the second requirement, ideally here at StackOverflow every post should be unique in nature.

Comment: Good idea, I will do that tomorrow, I'm limited to one question every 3 days.
I could copy you the whole HTML page in a doc, would that help?

Comment: Yeah that should be fine.

Comment: do you know another way to share the HTML Code? PasteBin marks the code as offensive and doesnt let me create a link

Comment: copy everything in a text file and upload it free file hosting website they will give you shareable link.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. It’s a new question now

Comment: great! You should ideally close this question by accepting the answer. thanks.

Comment: do you know how to include the preceding sibling in //*[starts-with(text(),'1/')] expression? Sorry to bother you again, I just can't get my head around it